# Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to this policy issue. (Google Play Console)

Tags: android

I've uploaded an ecommerce app to Play Store. But my app was rejected due to following reasons:-
We found the following issue(s) with your app:
Eligibility Issue
During testing we experienced stability issues with your app and were unable to successfully evaluate it for policy compliance. Please make sure your app behaves predictably at runtime and does not crash, hang, or display error messages.
About Families Policy Requirements
If one of the target audiences for your app is children, you must comply with the Families Policy Requirements.

App status: Rejected
Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to this policy issue. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
Hi Developers at _______(name deleted by myself),
After a recent review, we found that your app __________(name deleted by myself) is not compliant with one or more of our Developer Program Policies. See below for more information about your app’s status and how to correct the issue.
Reasons of violation
Issue with your app
We found the following issue(s) with your app:
Version(s)  Eligibility Issue
App Bundle:1    App stability
During testing we experienced stability issues with your app and were unable to successfully evaluate it for policy compliance. Please make sure your app behaves predictably at runtime and does not crash, hang, or display error messages.
Reasons of violation
About Families Policy Requirements
If one of the target audiences for your app is children, you must comply with the Families Policy Requirements.
Publishing Status
App status: Rejected
Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to this policy issue. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
Action required: Submit an updated app for review

1. Read through the Families Policy Requirements (and the Designed for Families Program Requirements, if applicable) and make appropriate changes to your app.
2. Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies before saving your changes.
3. Sign in to your Play Console, upload the modified, policy compliant APK across all tracks, and deactivate the non-compliant APK(s).
   To deactivate a non-compliant APK, please create a new release and upload a compliant APK to the same track.
   Be sure to increment the APK version number and set the release to 100% rollout, in order to successfully override and deactivate the non-compliant APK.

   I've tested my app on different version of android real devices as well as emulator.No issues. 
    I've selected all age group in  Target audience and content . But definitely there is nothing harm to children. It is an ecommerce app for purchase of groceries , fruits , vegetables , house hold products etc. 
   What I'm doing wrong. Is it a policy issue or app stability issue?? Please help

Comment: I think your app getting crash while testing by google developers or AI. So they not able to review it. My suggestion : Just test your release build in multiple devices. And check either it is working properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues here:

1 App stability. - See the google tests and fix the issues.
2 Wrong category. Shopping apps are not for families. kids shouldn't buy things, obviously. - Change your app description in the store listing.

Answer (score 0):

we realized that these 'stability issues' can also mean that the app hangs on it's loading screen when downloading Asset Packs via Play Asset Delivery. These downloads work only when apps are downloaded from the Play Store, which seems not to be the case when reviewing an App for Policy Compliance.
You can see if your App works outside the Play Store if you watch your pre-launch report videos.